# How i can store an API body response and use it in other test on cypress?

Tags: api, postman, cypress

I have this code to store response.body.address_id and use it in the next test but not working.
this is my hole code (two tests) :

```
`it('Create Address',function(){      
  return cy.request({
  method:'POST',
  url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/address/api/v1/addresses`,
  headers:{
    Authorization : `${Cypress.env('access_token')}`,
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
  },
body:{

    "address_name": "Home",
    "locality_area_street": "16th district",
    "city": "DAKAR",
    "country": "SENEGAL",        
}}          
  ).then((response)=>{
    expect(response.status).to.eq(201)
    Cypress.env('address_id', response.body.address_id);
  })

}) 
it('Add Address',function(){   
 cy.request({
  method:'PUT',
  url: 'https://api/v1/cart/address',
  headers:{
    Authorization : `Bearer ${Cypress.env('access_token')}`,
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',

  },
body:{
  "addressType": "BILLING",
  "id": `${Cypress.env('address_id')}`

}}          
  ).then((response)=>{
    cy.log(Cypress.env('address_id'));        
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
  })
})
```

})`

Can somme one help me to find a solution ?

Comment: What error is being thrown, or what issue is happening when using this code? At first glance it _looks_ ok... I'm probably missing something

Comment: When a copy it manualy on postman and past it, it works fine but on my script i get 403

Comment: Does your first request succeed? You have a difference in authorization between the two calls, and 403 would make me think I didn't have the correct auth. The first does not have `Bearer`, the second does.

Comment: both have bearer token on my code

Comment: And it log the address id in the first but it doesn't put it on the second test

Comment: First: `Authorization : \`${Cypress.env('access_token')}\`,`; Second: `Authorization : \`Bearer ${Cypress.env('access_token')}\`,`

Comment: yes i have change it but i have the same result

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use the `Cypress.env` for this,

Try this:

```
it("Create Address", function () {
  return cy
    .request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${Cypress.env("API_URL")}/address/api/v1/addresses`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${Cypress.env("access_token")}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: {
        address_name: "Home",
        locality_area_street: "16th district",
        city: "DAKAR",
        country: "SENEGAL",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(201);
      Cypress.env("address_id", response.body.address_id);

      this.address_id = response.body.address_id;
    });
});
it("Add Address", function () {
  cy.request({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "https://api/v1/cart/address",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${Cypress.env("access_token")}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: {
      addressType: "BILLING",
      id: this.address_id,
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    cy.log(this.address_id);
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: Not working :
I should put it into double quote ""